# Select/Option values as NULL

Tags: php, html

What I need is if I choose first option from a list, which is `---------------` and press submit button then they should return a NULL value in my database.

I tried to put this in my code:

```
if ($_POST['fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA'] === '') {
    $_POST['fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA'] = NULL;
}
```

But it's not working, my page show me same problem, that `fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA` badly entered.

There is my code:

```
<p>
        <label class="field" for="fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA">Komanda<?php echo in_array('fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA', $required) ? '<span> *</span>' : ''; ?></label>
        <select id="fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA" name="fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA">
            <option value="-1">---------------</option>
            <?php
                $kom = $asmuoObj->getkomanda();
                foreach($kom as $key => $val) {
                    $selected = "";
                    if(isset($data['fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA']) && $data['fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA'] == $val['id']) {
                            $selected = " selected='selected'";}
                    echo "<option{$selected} value='{$val['id']}'>{$val['pavadinimas']}</option>";}
            ?>
        </select>
</p>
```

UPDATE 1

That how my code looks like now, but my page showed me an errors.

```
<p>
<?php
              if ($_POST['fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA'] == '-1') {
              $_POST['fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA'] = NULL;}
?>
        <label class="field" for="fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA">Komanda<?php echo in_array('fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA', $required) ? '<span> *</span>' : ''; ?></label>
        <select id="fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA" name="fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA">
            <option value="-1">---------------</option>
            <?php
                $kom = $asmuoObj->getkomanda();
                foreach($kom as $key => $val) {
                    $selected = "";
                    if(isset($data['fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA']) && $data['fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA'] == $val['id']) {
                            $selected = " selected='selected'";}
                    echo "<option{$selected} value='{$val['id']}'>{$val['pavadinimas']}</option>";}
            ?>
        </select>
</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have set value `-1` to the option.

Two options:

1) Change option value to blank "".

```
<option value="">---------------</option>
```

2) At PHP submit side, add `if` condition

```
if ($_POST['fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA'] == -1) {
 $fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Replace this code: `if ($_POST['fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA'] === '') {' By `if ($_POST['fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA'] === '-1') {`

Answer (score 2):

You are not setting your condition right. You need to put -1, not empty in your if statement. Because when selected ------------ it's value is -1.

```
if ($_POST['fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA'] == '-1') {
  $_POST['fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA'] = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your complete code and I'll tell you where to put it?

Comment: You need to show us part where you insert in DB. This code is for that part.

Comment: I'm a little confused.. I put this code `if ($_POST['fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA'] == '-1') {
  $_POST['fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA'] = NULL;
}` but there is an error.

Comment: That `fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA` badly entered.

Comment: Can you c/p message you get? What does it mean badly entered? It's not PHP message.